# Why my python multi process code runs very slow?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
# multi-processes
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        self.process_num = 10 <------------ 10 processes
        self.count = 0

    def start(self):
        for i in range(self.process_num):
            p = Process(target = self.run)
            p.start()
            p.join()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.count += 1
            user = self.queue.get()
            # do something not so fast like time.sleep(1)
            print self.count
            if self.queue.empty():
                break
```

I use **Worker().start(queue)** to start the program, but the output is not so fast as i expected(Seems only one process are running).

Is there any problem in my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're only running one process at a time, you're waiting for each process to terminate before starting the next;

```
def start(self):
    for i in range(self.process_num):
        p = Process(target = self.run)
        p.start()                       <-- starts a new process
        p.join()                        <-- waits for the process to terminate
```

In other words, you're starting 10 processes, but the second one won't start until the first one terminates and so on.

For what you're trying to do, it may be better not to use `Process` manually and instead use a [Process Pool](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool).

Comment: Thanks, that make sense, but if i want to use it manually, where should i put the join method ? I want my main process wait for those sub processes.

Comment: Tricky one. If it's ok to just wait for all processes to terminate, then loop as you do now and add the Process to an array. When you're done starting them all, just loop the array and Join() them one by one. If the main process is to continue doing other things, you'll need to instead occasionally (main loop) run through the array and Join() with a timeout of 0, keeping track of which Processes have terminated and removing them from the array. Side note; I'm not aware of any way to get notified when a sub-process terminates but I always use Process Pool so there may be a way I don't know of.